# Navigate between text boxes in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, keyboard-navigation

I want to navigate between text boxes (for example, title and body, or between more body boxes) within a slide in PowerPoint 2010 using the keyboard, but I can't figure out how to do that. According to the [Microsoft support page](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-use-while-creating-a-presentation-in-powerpoint-2010-HP010336519.aspx) CTRL+ENTER does something similar (at least for forward navigation) but it always creates a new slide for me. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:** I discovered that CTRL+ENTER works, just not how I expect it. If I am on a title box, it creates a new slide, and if I am on a body box, it jumps to the title, while it would be logical in the other direction. Anyway, what I want is to navigate in both directions between boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TAB from one object to another (Shift-Tab to reverse order).
When you are on the text box you want, use F2 to edit the contents.

Comment: If I'm currently editing it, hogy do I get "out" of it? Because in this case TAB just inserts a tab character.

Comment: ESC is the key you need

Comment: ENTER also allows you to edit the selected text box

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tab tip!  To get into and out of editing press F2 (that is, if editing, F2 selects the box, if the box is selected, F2 highlights the text and enables editing).  Combine that with Tab and Shift+Tab, and you should be able to get around the page pretty well.